# LibGDX create a 3D mapeditor

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

i whant to make for my game a 3D mapeditor.

Now I have some questions:

1. What format should I save the map? I saw from a tutorial scenes could be loaded by a g3db file.
2. If g3db files are good to go.. How to reference from the map file to the object to not duplicate objects in a scene.
3. How should I manage collision? In an file that defines the collision?

Comment: I am planning to create a 3D map editor too. My idea is to create objects, for example in blender and then convert them into g3db format. I use Bullet Physics, so it should be possible to define rigid bodies also in Blender and export them some how. I would choose to create my own format for a whole map definition (e.g. json), which will reference single g3db files and physics informations for collision detection and so.. You can create your own loader which will build your level from classic libgdx classes, such as Model, ModelInstance, Environement etc. This is just my idea how to do it.

Comment: Well the idea should be good but in this tutorial: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/ he says its better to do a scene in a g3db file and not put g3db files together to a scene.

Comment: For collision shapes, both libgdx and blender support the .bullet file format (keep in mind though that blender uses z-up). You can use g3dj/g3db for maps (if you dont need animations/skinning), its format is just json, so if you like you can add whatever information you like to it. If you prefer your own file format then use that. I'd probably use a combination of the two: one map file that references the nodes in a g3db/j file. Either way, don't try to solve problems that don't exist.

Comment: Are there other ways to save maps provided by libGDX?